# If database row = null, print something, else print something else

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a seat booking system, and i need to check via MySQL if the seat X is available. If there is a name assigned to it, print "sorry, this seat is already taken", else if there is no name assigned to it (default 0), print "available!".

This is what i tried:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect(localhost, root, root);
mysql_select_db(room); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result  = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = 'A1'");
if ($result  == '0') {
        echo 'available!';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, this seat is already taken.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the data from the query.

Comment: Your second if statement ... compare it with your first one in terms of syntax

Comment: what about mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = 'A1'");

Comment: Rizier123 - corrected! still not working though.

Comment: 1) stop using old mysql_* functions. 2) you're using the $result variable wrongly. Take a look at a tutorial, you need to either count the number of rows returned from the query or fetch the data returned for actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should considered moving away from the mysql_* functions. Either way, you should be doing something like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
$result  = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = 'A1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($results) == 0) {
    echo 'available!';
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, this seat is already taken.';
}
```

You've also got an extra `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result  = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = 'A1'");
     if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        echo 'available!';
     }else {
            echo 'Sorry, this seat is already taken.';
        }
```

Comment: just look at it again. you'll see it

Comment: should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "room");
if ($link->connect_errno)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if (($result = $link->query("SELECT name FROM seats WHERE seat = 'A1'") && $result->num_rows)
{
    echo 'Sorry, this seat is already taken.';
}
else
{
    $result->close();
    echo 'available!';
}
```

This is using the new [MySQLi library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and should properly check whether a result was returned with any rows. Checking `$result->num_rows` may not be necessary, as `$result` should be empty if no rows were returned.

Comment: the new MySQLi library seems much less logic and friendly than the older one!

Comment: Agreed! It's also safer and faster. It might be a bit confusing to adjust to if you've been using `mysql_*` for a while, but it's worth it!